# How to do web app and api security when the source code is easily viewed?

Tags: rest, security, asp.net-web-api

My web application uses a reactive front-end that gets data from an API. The API is secured using a hand rolled solution, which has been secure enough for my needs (nothing financial), but to stay ahead of trouble, I'm thinking about replacing it with dedicated middleware written by people who specialize in security.

I understand how solutions like OAuth provide security by using private keys that you share in advance between the API and the callers of the API.

The thing I don't understand is: the primary caller of my API is my own web app client, and that runs in the browser, where the source code can be viewed. How can I secure a call from that client to the API when there is no way to store secret data on the client?

Comment: "where the source code can be viewed", what do you mean by that? JavaScript code or C# code?

Comment: I mean JavaScript, because my app is a web app. Everything is minified and obfucated, but is still fairly easily viewed. I suppose in this way a C# app is just as insecure, because it can be easily decompiled. So the question is the same: how to enable secure communication between client and server, when the client code is not secure?

Comment: You will have to hire a security expert to analyze and explain the details. Security is too huge a topic, and many tips like "Assume Zero Trust" are well known, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/security/security-principles